# Deploy a docker stack on one node (co-schedule containers like docker swarm)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I'm aware that docker-compose with docker-swarm (which is now legacy) is able to co-schedule some services on one node (using dependency filters such as link)

I was wondering if this kind of co-scheduling is possible using modern docker engine swarm mode and the new stack deployment introduced in Docker 1.13

In docker-compose file version 3, links are said to be ignored while deploying a stack in a swarm, so obviously links aren't the solution.

We have a bunch of servers to run batch short-running jobs and the network between them is not very high speed. We want to run each batch job (which consists of multiple containers) on one server to avoid networking overhead. Is this feature implemented in docker stack or docker swarm mode or we should use the legacy docker-swarm?

Also, I couldn't find co-scheduling with another container in the placement policies.

Comment: Hey. Have you found a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman: You are right.

To deploy to a specific node you need to use placement policy:

```
version: '3'
services:

  job1:
    image: example/job1
    deploy:
      placement:
        node.hostname: node-1
    networks:
      - example

  job2:
    image: example/job2
   deploy:
      placement:
        node.hostname: node-1
    networks:
      - example

networks:
  example:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: I didn't want to run containers on a specific node. I wanted to make sure two containers will run on the same node which is more abstract.

Answer (score -2):

You can still use [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dependson)

It worth having a look at [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize#waiting-for-other-dependencies) too.

Comment: depends and dockerize start contains in an ordered sequence, but do not make them run on the same node.